# how to make fastlane compatible with iOS13

Tags: ios13, fastlane

I'm using fastlane to pack my app, i've write some ios 13 supported class in my app, such as UIStatusBarManager class, then it pack failed, what should i do?

i have update the fastlane to latest version, but xcode is still xcode10.

Here is the error what i got when i use fastlane to pack:

```
[11:04:05]: ▸ ❌  /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m:909:9: use of undeclared identifier 'UIStatusBarManager'
[11:04:05]: ▸         UIStatusBarManager *statusBarManager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager;
[11:04:05]: ▸         ^
[11:04:05]: ▸ ❌  /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m:909:29: use of undeclared identifier 'statusBarManager'
[11:04:05]: ▸         UIStatusBarManager *statusBarManager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager;
[11:04:05]: ▸                             ^
[11:04:05]: ▸ ❌  /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m:909:92: property 'windowScene' not found on object of type 'UIWindow *'
[11:04:05]: ▸         UIStatusBarManager *statusBarManager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager;
[11:04:05]: ▸                                                                                            ^
[11:04:05]: ▸ ❌  /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m:910:14: use of undeclared identifier 'statusBarManager'
[11:04:05]: ▸         if ([statusBarManager respondsToSelector:@selector(createLocalStatusBar)]) {
[11:04:05]: ▸              ^
[11:04:05]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[11:04:05]: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[11:04:05]: ▸   CompileC /Users/wanghq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Teacher_iOS-faqbabrkmkezsveufzeljjrkqytg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Teacher_iOS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Teacher_iOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/Teacher_iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ZFPlayerView.o /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[11:04:05]: ▸ (1 failure)
[11:04:05]: ▸ ❌  /Users/wanghq/jenkins_workspaces/workspace/mobile-ios-teacher-ipa/Teacher_iOS/Train/Record/Utils/ZFPlayer/ZFPlayerView.m:911:40: use of undeclared identifier 'statusBarManager'
```

and this the Build environment:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+
|            Build environment            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.134.0                 |
| export_method | development             |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS12.2.sdk        |
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

please help me, thanks！

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Xcode 11 or newer to use the iOS 13 SDK.

Fastlane can't do anything the underlying build system can't do. I presume you'd get the same error building directly in Xcode 10. Since you're invoking parts of the API like UIStatusBarManager that don't exist in the iOS 12.2 SDK, the compiler doesn't know what to do with that.

Update Xcode and target the iOS 13 (or 13.1) SDK.

Answer (score 0):

- If your modifications are just a preparation to XCode 11 or iOS 13,
- If your modifications don't need to active at runtime by now,
- If you want to continue with your XCode 10.x version by now,

then you can use "compiler conditional directives" for problematic code sections.

For instance, I have XCode 10.3 and I can compile project with below modification.

[image: suggested change for compiler]

Comment: i have updated xcode to version 11.1, so the problem have solved, but also thank you !